# Tool to mock Amazon's SimpleDB locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mocking, amazon-simpledb

An app the company I work for is using Amazon SimpleDB. I have been tasked to write tests for that app. I am looking for a tool to mock SimpleDB locally and filling it with some dummy data, so that I don't always make requests.

I found [SimpleDB/dev](https://code.google.com/p/simpledb-dev/) but it is using the old API, and the app I am supposed to test uses the new 2009 API. I also found about [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto), but that doesn't solve my issue either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just have them setup a test SimpleDB using the real amazon system.  It is 14 cents per hour.  You'll spend far more time (which has a cost) trying to get a mock system to work and you won't even be sure if it works on the real stuff.  Use the real stuff.

Comment: Yes, this seems like the most reasonable thing to do. Thanks!

Comment: You can use SDBExplorer http://www.sdbexplorer.com. You can perform multiple parallel data uploads. It will save your time in uploading dummy data. Give it try. It's free for 30 days.